# UIWebView: fill screen with PDF file

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

There's a `UIWebView` in my iOS app containing a PDF file. This PDF file is very wide. When opening this view the device fits the content to the screen. But it should rather fill the screen and "cut" the file.

It is like this: [image]

But it should be like this when starting the app/view: [image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_ImageInWebView loadRequest:request];
    [_ImageInWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting setScalesPageToFit to NO?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it didn't help. Any other idea?

Comment: Try to set setScalesPageToFit to NO and `_ImageInWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it is still the same problem.

Comment: Do you have more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things at play here. Scaling the page to fit the screen will produce the image that is seen on top (where the whole width of the image fits on the screen). This is not what we want in this case, so we should disable setScalesPageToFit. The OP already mentioned that this alone did not work for them.

Another thing that we should do after we disable scaling is to navigate to the portion of the PDF we would like displayed. The solution might vary depending on project specific settings. There would also be a difference if auto layout is on or off.

This is what I've used in the past to center a PDF in a web view. Note that I've used this code with tall PDF files, but should work with wide ones as well after minor modifications.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_MSEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CGFloat topInset = floor(([[self _ImageInWebView] frame].size.height - [[[self _ImageInWebView] scrollView] contentSize].height) / 2);
    [[[self _ImageInWebView] scrollView] setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, 0, 0, 0)];
    [[[self _ImageInWebView] scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -topInset) animated:NO];
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still didn't menage to solve my problem. Is there anybody else who can help me?

Comment: What was the result when you tried the code? Did anything change?

Comment: I just got error messages. I think this code isn't suitable for my problem.